# Override hybris commonI18NService roundCurrency method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, sap-commerce-cloud

Trying to override `spring bean` using `Alias`.

I want to over ride `roundCurrency` method of `commonI18NService`

OOTB definition

```
<alias alias="commonI18NService" name="defaultCommonI18NService"/>
<bean id="defaultCommonI18NService" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.i18n.impl.DefaultCommonI18NService"  parent="abstractBusinessService">
    <property name="languageDao" ref="languageDao"/>
    <property name="currencyDao" ref="currencyDao"/>
    <property name="countryDao" ref="countryDao"/>
    <property name="regionDao" ref="regionDao"/>
    <property name="conversionStrategy" ref="conversionStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

Our custom code :-

```
public class DefaultCustomCommonI18NService extends DefaultCommonI18NService
{

    @Override
    public double roundCurrency(double value, int digits)
    {
      // custom logic
        return value;
    }
}
```

Inject custom bean :-

```
<alias alias="commonI18NService" name="defaultCustomCommonI18NService"/>
<bean id="defaultCustomCommonI18NService" class="com.extended.service.impl.DefaultCustomCommonI18NService"  parent="defaultCommonI18NService"/>
```

But it throws exception on server startUP

```
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Loading <<application>> spring config <master> from extension (saporderexchangeb2b) located in (saporderexchangeb2b-spring.xml) took: (121.4 ms)
WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listMergeBeanPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commercePlaceOrderMethodHooksListMergeDirective' defined in class path resource [b2bapprovalprocess-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'b2bApprovalBusinessProcessCreationPlaceOrderMethodHook' while setting bean property 'add'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'b2bApprovalBusinessProcessCreationPlaceOrderMethodHook' defined in class path resource [b2bapprovalprocess-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'defaultB2BCreateOrderFromCartStrategy' while setting bean property 'businessProcessCreationStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultB2BCreateOrderFromCartStrategy' defined in class path resource [b2bapprovalprocess-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cloneAbstractOrderStrategy' while setting bean property 'cloneAbstractOrderStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCloneAbstractOrderStrategy' defined in class path resource [order-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'typeService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTypeService' defined in class path resource [servicelayer-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'converterRegistry' while setting bean property 'converterRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultConverterRegistry' defined in class path resource [servicelayer-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'commonI18NService': : No qualifying bean of type [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.i18n.CommonI18NService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: defaultCommonI18NService,defaultcustomCommonI18NService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.i18n.CommonI18NService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: defaultCommonI18NService,defaultcustomCommonI18NService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the autowiring strategy of `defaultConverterRegistry` is `byType`:

```
<bean id="defaultConverterRegistry" ... autowire="byType" >
```

which means **Spring** found two candidates for `commonI18NService` bean `defaultCommonI18NService` and `defaultcustomCommonI18NService` hence don't know which one to inject.

I propose to make your `defaultcustomCommonI18NService` a primary bean to be the autowired by using `primary="true"`, [see](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)

```
<bean id="defaultCustomCommonI18NService" class="com.extended.service.impl.DefaultCustomCommonI18NService"  parent="defaultCommonI18NService" primary="true" />
```

Comment: How do you find `defaultConverterRegistry` is causing the problem? I am not able to see source of that class. Assuming 'defaultConverterRegistry' have commonI18NService as @Autowired

Comment: it's declared here : ...\hybris\bin\platform\ext\core\resources\servicelayer-spring.xml and it's present in the stacktrace you give

Comment: And if you want to see the source of DefaultModelConverterRegistry.class you need to use a java decompiler.

Comment: I didn't find any stacktrace related to `DefaultModelConverterRegistry`, Also I have tried to check source of `DefaultModelConverterRegistry` using decompiler but no luck.. I assume this class has Autowired `commonI18NService` which was causing the issue.